# navigate within index.html using cordova and phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a cordova/phonegap project and I want to navigate in the same index.html but give the impression to the user that he opened a new page? (Without ionic framework)

I put the following code in index.html but it does not give that impression:

```
<div id="page_01">
    <a href="#page_02">Press for Next step</a>>
</div>
<div id="page_02">
    <p>New page for the user but it is in the same index.html</p>
</div>
```